# Where can I find HTML5 metadata?

Tags: html

I need the list of tagnames, interface names, attributes of each tagname (the name and the type) and the relations between them.

The info at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ is unformated and in an unprocessable format.

The ["Index elements" from *HTML 5.1 2nd Edition* at w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/fullindex.html#index-elements) have better info but not in a structured format (json, csv, xml, etc).

Comment: You could try to find unofficial DTD or XSD for HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is machine-readable/can be parsed, so not sure what you mean by "unprocesable". The document containing the information you desire [may as well be valid markup](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fhtml.spec.whatwg.org%2Fmultipage%2F), but more importantly proves its parseable.

Alternatively, if you view source, there is a script [`html-dfn.js`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/html-dfn.js),
 and if you follow that you can see that it calls [`xrefs.json`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/xrefs.json), which I'm assuming renders those pages.

Alternatively, alternatively, WHATWG offers a very non-open data format flavor ala [PDF](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/print.pdf) which is visible form the main navigation.

Comment: Yes I can parse https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/fullindex.html#index-elements, but I hope is there an open structured format

Comment: yes, the document you submitted is an open (well) structured format. but i also linked to JSON that has the same content/data.

Comment: what did your search return? mine shows 7 results